# Why shouldn't I destroy http session on user logout?

Tags: jsf, session, authentication, javabeans, invalidation

Is there any good reason not to simply destroy the HTTP session like:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
```

instead of just deauthenticating the user and make sure to clean user data from the session scoped beans?

Comment: Well, the user is authenticated against a session bean. Not much about it: it holds the user name on successful authentication. For me the problem is that you may accidentally leave user related data on the session after deauthentication, in other session beans (not that I can think of a good example, because I don't have any session scoped input forms (and probably shouldn't have, that's what the view scope is for I guess) or anything like that. The app is on an early dev stage...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do both. Deauthenticating the user can depend on your implementation. If you call out to a third party system to obtain a security token for a user, chances are you have to call back again to invalidate the token.

You also have to invalidate the HttpSession. Invalidating the session will release all session scoped beans. It also releases JSF view states and component trees for pages visited during the user's session. These can make the session sizeable and not invalidating will leave the heap full of sessions waiting to timeout and that have a negative impact on the server's capacity.

BTW, you can invalidate the session without the need to obtain the HttpSession, like so:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the answer in Oracle documentation:

> The session.invalidate() method, which is often used to log out a
>   user, only invalidates the current session for a user—the user's
>   authentication information still remains valid and is stored in the
>   context of the server or virtual host. If the server or virtual host
>   is hosting only one Web application, the session.invalidate() method,
>   in effect, logs out the user.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/sessions.html#wp150374